# Multiple JSON Requests Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems, rest-client

Im using rails for with the crunchbase api to pull down the info for companies and I've been battling this error all night. It completes **one** request successfully and after constructing the second request it crashes and I receive this error:

```
Error/Users/Rich/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse':
(<unknown>): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

I can post as much code as necessary. All help is much appreciated as I'm a ruby newbie.

```
def get_data(company_links)
  while i < company_links.length
    puts "USING URL #{URL}#{company_links[i]}.js?#{API_Key}"
    resp = RestClient.get("#{URL}#{company_links[i]}.js?#{API_Key}")
    arr = Crack::JSON.parse(resp)
    i += 1
  end
end
```

calling the method

```
links_array = ["dropbox","twitter"]
get_data(links_array)
```

**Edit Answer Found**
Don't really know why it works but im not complaining that its solved. Thanks to everyone who provided assistance I really appreciate it :)

```
def get_data(links_array)
    links_array.each do |company|
    puts "USING URL #{URL}#{company}.js?#{API_Key}"
    resp = RestClient.get("#{URL}#{company}.js?#{API_Key}")
    arr = JSON.parse(resp)
    puts arr["name"]
  end
end
```

Comment: Is `def get_data(...)` the first line of your file? The error message suggests that the error occurs in line 1, column 1

Comment: Is that referring to the first line of the file or the response? My first line is require 'rubygems'

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your problem is in the JSON you're getting back, not the fetching of it. Diagnose with:

```
def get_data(company_links)
  company_links.each do |company|
    puts "USING URL #{URL}#{company}.js?#{API_Key}"
    resp = RestClient.get("#{URL}#{company}.js?#{API_Key}")
    puts "RETURNS: #{resp}"
    arr = Crack::JSON.parse(resp)
  end
end
```

Also try

```
links_array = ["twitter","dropbox"]
get_data(links_array)
```

and see if it fails on the first or second request.

Edit: I'm betting you've got some character Crack/Psych doesn't like at the very beginning of your JSON string, and that it's a "control character" ;)

Edit2: If the JSON printed to the console is valid, try `arr = Crack::JSON.parse(resp.to_s)` or `arr = Crack::JSON.parse(resp.inspect)`. I'm fuzzy on a lot of the important details here.

Comment: Really appreciate the help I've been going through your suggestions and its a really weird error. The json it prints for one company is perfectly valid and then it dies. Edit 2 produced a different error though: /Users/Rich/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)

Comment: Run each get manually in the console and add the results of `puts resp` to your question. Too hard to diagnose from "here".

Comment: Found the answer, no idea why this worked but it does by replacing:Crack::JSON.parse(resp) with just JSON.parse(resp)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why exactly this happening but, instead of using while loop, you might consider using threads to run multiple requests. I personally do not think looping requests is a good idea.

Take a look at this example:

[Ruby on Rails Multiple HTTP request at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050910/ruby-on-rails-multiple-http-request-at-the-same-time)